# how can i take an input from the user in p5.js code?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i want to take an input from the user and after the input the code must run...
I want to change the button "click me" as input from the user the code must run after getting input from the user.

```js
var playAnim=false;
var pic1;
var pic2;
var pic3;
let button;
let posX=0
let posY=0
const rightwall=350;
const height=600;

function preload(){
  pic1=loadImage("5.png")
  pic2=loadImage("iron.jpg")
  pic3=loadImage("slagmetal.jpg")
  
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background("blue");
  button =createButton('CLICK ME');
  button.position(200,250);
  button.mousePressed(changeBG);
  noLoop();
}
function changeBG() {
  let val = random(65);
  background(val);
  loop();
  playAnim=true;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);

 
  img1=image(pic1, 300, 30, 150, 200)
  img2=image(pic2, posX, 70, 100, 100)
  img3=image(pic3,posX, posY-300,150, 200)
  if (playAnim) {
  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
  }
  

 // posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
 // posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
}
```

i want to take an input at "click me" button and after that the code must run.
the code consists of two moving images and after taking an input from user the code must run.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "take an input from the user"? Do you mean you want the user to have to type in some text?

Comment: not actually ,i want that when someone clicks on the click me button it must create an input of weights suppose the user want to take 200gms or 300 gms or 500gms like .

Comment: how can i add event listener in p5.js?

Comment: There no need to add event listeners , as per documentation of P5.js , on button.mousePressed(changeBG); the function will run , you can add logic of moving images inside the function of changeBg , function draw() call the function inside changeBG method body.

Comment: how can i connect with you sir..if i need more help in p5.js?

Answer (score 1):

There no need to add event listeners , as per documentation of P5.js , on button.mousePressed(changeBG); the function will run , you can add logic of moving images inside the function of changeBg , function draw() call the function inside changeBG method body.

```js
var playAnim=false;
var pic1;
var pic2;
var pic3;
let button;
let posX=0
let posY=0
const rightwall=350;
const height=600;

function preload(){
  pic1=loadImage("5.png")
  pic2=loadImage("iron.jpg")
  pic3=loadImage("slagmetal.jpg")
  
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background("blue");
  button =createButton('CLICK ME');
  button.position(200,250);
  button.mousePressed(changeBG);
  noLoop();
}
function changeBG() {
  let val = random(65);
  background(val);
  loop();
  playAnim=true;
  draw();
  // background will be overwritten with 220
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);

 
  img1=image(pic1, 300, 30, 150, 200)
  img2=image(pic2, posX, 70, 100, 100)
  img3=image(pic3,posX, posY-300,150, 200)
  if (playAnim) {
  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
  }
  

 // posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
 // posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
}
```

Comment: the cdde is not working @Pranavjeet.mishra

Comment: is there any error in console , debug the flow of function execution

Comment: error in console showing

Comment: Please post the console error

Comment:  p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path (https://preview.p5js.org/iron.jpg) is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server. (More info at https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server) 
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0…}

 p5.js says: It looks like there was a problem loading your image. Try checking if the file path (https://preview.p5js.org/slagmetal.jpg) is correct, hosting the file online, or running a local server. (More info at https://githuB

Answer (score 0):

Try do this

```
if (key == //you enter the input that user will type) {
  // enter your code
}
```

Go to https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-p5js/lessons/p5js-interaction/exercises/p5js-using-key-input for any further info

**My code is only for 1 key**